# calculatiing Image size & position by using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext & drawRect to collage imageView in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uigraphicscontext

I'm trying to create a collage image using **UIGraphicsBeginImageContext**. But cropping a specific position of a image and placing the imageView to a proper position in a view driving me nuts. My attempt so far:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self noOfImages:2]; // no of images method used for how many image you want to show in the view. Currently I needed a collage imageView upto 3 images
}

-(void)noOfImages:(int)num
{
    if (num==2)
    {
        UIImageView *One=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, containerView.frame.size.width, containerView.frame.size.height)];
        [One setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [One setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];

        UIImageView *Two=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(containerView.frame.size.width/2, 0, containerView.frame.size.width/2, containerView.frame.size.height)];
        [Two setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

        NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"jpg"];
        UIImage *existingImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];


        // Create new image context (retina safe)
         UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(200, 200), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

         // Create rect for image
         CGRect rect = CGRectMake(1, 0, containerView.frame.size.width, containerView.frame.size.height);

         // Draw the image into the rect
         [existingImage drawInRect:rect];

         // Saving the image, ending image context
         UIImage * newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
         UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [Two setImage:newImage];


        [containerView addSubview:One];
        [containerView addSubview:Two];
    }

    else if (num==3)
    {
        UIImageView *One=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, containerView.frame.size.width, containerView.frame.size.height)];
        [One setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [One setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];

        UIImageView *Two=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(containerView.frame.size.width/2, 0, containerView.frame.size.width/2, containerView.frame.size.height/2)];
        [Two setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

        NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"2" ofType:@"jpg"];
        UIImage *existingImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];


        // Create new image context (retina safe)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(200, 200), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

        // Create rect for image
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(1, 0, containerView.frame.size.width, 200);

        // Draw the image into the rect
        [existingImage drawInRect:rect];

        // Saving the image, ending image context
        UIImage * newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [Two setImage:newImage];

        UIImageView *Three=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(containerView.frame.size.width/2, containerView.frame.size.height/2, containerView.frame.size.width/2, containerView.frame.size.height/2)];
        [Three setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];

        NSString *imagePath3 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3" ofType:@"jpg"];
        UIImage *existingImage3 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePath3];


        // Create new image context (retina safe)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(200, 200), NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

        // Create rect for image
        CGRect rect3 = CGRectMake(1, 0, containerView.frame.size.width, 200);

        // Draw the image into the rect
        [existingImage3 drawInRect:rect3];

        // Saving the image, ending image context
        UIImage * newImage3 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [Three setImage:newImage3];

        [containerView addSubview:One];
        [containerView addSubview:Two];
        [containerView addSubview:Three];
    }
}
```

Output for two Images should be:

[image]

Output for three Images should be:

[image]

Actually when I'm using 200x200 images, the outputs are correct.But this code doesn't work from dynamic images which height & width are unknown to me. Also the right side image is little bit stretched and not in correct position for tow images.The right side image's) x position should start from the middle point to end, not the starting point to middle. I know my calculations are wrong. But can't set the proper height, width,position or crop using  **UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions**  or the **imageview** which is added as a subview.

I need output like:
for two images- first image's one half at the left and the other image half right.
for three images-first image's one half at the left and the 2nd image's half at top right and third image's half at bottom right.

Comment: Your question is not clear. We need to know more specifically how you want to crop and place the images. You showed images, but we don't know what you want them to look like, nor what's wrong with the images you show.

Answer (score 0):

Make the second image bigger proportionally and then position it where it should. It'll be easier for you to code it straight in your project.